# Populating Multi dimensional array in octave/matlab to create waterfall plot in octave / matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

I'm trying to create a Multi dimensional array so I can create a waterfall plot in octave, a matlab type of program.  **(Please note octave does not have the waterfall plot option so I have to make a work around.**

I have multiple arrays that have frequency in the first column and amplitude in the second column.
example: When looped through the arrays, which are called **sort_array** they each need to be placed into a multidimensional array on a separate page.

```
4000, .5
3002, .1234
1093, .7
```

I was trying to have each of these arrays **(sort_array)** added to a single multidimensional array by using a for loop to have everything added to one array to make it easier to plot and export as a text file.  I also thought using **k** as the page option for the multiple dimension array.  But I keep getting dimensions mismatch.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Please note I left out the sort_array code and just included the example array called **sort_array** above as an example of what the array would look like.  There will be about 9000 of them.

```
md=[];
for k=1:9000 
md_tmp=[sort_array(:,1),sort_array(:,2)]
ma(:,:,k)=[ma;ma_tmp];
end
```

So when I type in **ma(:,:,1)** I would get

```
4000, .5
3002, .1234
1093, .7
```

and if I type in ma(:,:,2) I would get the next one.

thanks

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @Dan how can I add multiple arrays (sort_array in my example) to 1 multidimensional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here: `ma(:,:,k)=[ma;ma_tmp];`

You are mixing up two concepts.

Either concatenate the new matrix onto the current one:

```
ma = [ma; ma_tmp];
```

***OR***

Assign the new matrix directly to the correct index (this is the cleaner, more efficient solution):

```
 ma(:,:,k) = ma_tmp;
```

But you can't do both.

Answer (score 0):

thanks I found a work around

```
sort_array=sortrows(arraytmp,-1); %sort by freq
k_tmp=repmat(k,length(sort_array(:,2)),1); %to create page for freq and amp in multidimensional array
ma_tmp=[sort_array(:,1),sort_array(:,2),k_tmp];
ma=[ma;ma_tmp];
```